# Issue when trying to import Jacoco code coverage to SonarQube: Cannot import coverage information for file, coverage data is invalid

Tags: kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm having some issues when trying to import Jacoco code coverage to SonarQube.

I am using SonarQube with Jacoco for importing test coverage results (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Unit+Tests+and+Coverage+Results+Import). Everything has worked well until i have **forEach** block in some method.

```
ERROR: Cannot import coverage information for file, coverage data is invalid. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 29 is out of range in the file (lines: 28)
```

If I remove **forEach** file then test coverage is correctly generated, but with **forEach** I get 0% coverage.

This happens only when i integrate it with sonarqube, if i run jacoco locally it works perfectly.

We use SonarQube Scanner 3.3.0.1492, SonarQube server 7.5.0.

Answer (score 11):

Search in Google by keywords `sonarqube` `kotlin` `jacoco` and

> `is out of range in the file`

reveals following page https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-kotlin-coverage-fails-due-to-line-is-out-of-range-errors/3201/18 , which states that problem was fixed in JaCoCo version `0.8.3` And which contains link to page https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/763 , which in its turn contains quite expressive explanation of problem, including explanations of why it affects SonarQube.

So make sure that you use JaCoCo version `0.8.3` or even better latest, which is `0.8.7` as of 8 September 2021.