# How to generate a Jacoco coverage report for android connected tests with Jacoco version 0.8.3+?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, jacoco

I am attempting to generate instrumentation test coverage reports in Gradle to send to SonarQube. As this is a Kotlin codebase, I need to use Jacoco version 0.8.3+ to generate the reports to avoid the issue outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134830/1088659).

The custom task I created for generating unit test coverage reports works fine with the specified Jacoco version. But instrumented test coverage reports generated with the `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` still generates a report with Jacoco version 0.7.9.

Is there a way to make `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` or some other way to create an instrumentation test coverage report with a newer version of Jacoco plugin 0.8.3+?

Relevant parts of the top level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.5"
    }
}
```

Relevant parts of the module level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin:"com.android.library"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {
    group "Reporting"
    description "Generate Jacoco coverage reports from unit tests."

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter =
        ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 
         'android/**/*.*']
    def javaDebugTree =
        fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def kotlinDebugTree =
        fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from.addAll(files([mainSrc]))
    classDirectories.from.addAll(files([javaDebugTree, kotlinDebugTree]))
    executionData.from.addAll(fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
            "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ]))
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}
```

Running the tasks sequentially `test` `connectedDebugAndroidTest` `jacocoTestReport` generates two sets of jacoco reports. The report from the connected tests with the older jacoco version, and the report for the unit tests with the correct jacoco version.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: any solution did you get it.